# Date + time zone correction

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to avoid time zone correction?:

```
2.4.0 :077 > @purchase_lot[0]
 => #<Protocol44 publishDate: "2018-09-27 21:49:04">

2.4.0 :078 > @purchase_lot[0]['publishDate']
 => Fri, 28 Sep 2018 00:49:04 MSK +03:00

2.4.0 :079 > @purchase_lot[0]['publishDate'].class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

The data come from the database (mariadb), the field type is DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

```
@purchase_lot[0]['publishDate'].utc
#=> 2018-09-27 21:49:04 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps is usually stored in UTC

To stop conversion to default timezone you can use `.utc` method

```
@purchase_lot[0]['publishDate'].utc
```